# Is there a way to create a custom command to choose the current date in cypress?

Tags: cypress

I have a date picker which I would like to choose the current date or a date in the future without having to reset each time.

Comment: Is your date field allow to type text?

Comment: Yes the field can take text

Comment: Then you can type the current date `var date = new Date();
var currentDate = (((date.getMonth() > 8) ? (date.getMonth() + 1) : ('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1))) + '/' + ((date.getDate() > 9) ? date.getDate() : ('0' + date.getDate())) + '/' + date.getFullYear())` and pass the `currentDate` to enter it.